# How do i add fontawesome icon to Kendo UI upload button

Tags: html, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-upload

I want to add font awesome icon to Kendo UI Upload Button

HTML Code :

```
<div class="row row-border lopUploadSet">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
            <input type="hidden" name="DocFileType" id="DocFileType1" value="14" />
            <div class="lopUploadLabel">
                <span>1</span>
                Driver's License
            </div>
        </div>
         <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-12 lopUploadInput"><input type="file" name="files" id="files1" class="clsfiles" />
         
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
            <a href="#" id="notes-toggle" class="lopUploadAddNotes"><i class="bi bi-chat-left-quote"></i> Add Notes</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 form-group notes-view" id="notes-box">
                <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Add Notes" id="Note1" name="Note" rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Generated Code :

```
<div class="col-md-5 col-sm-12 lopUploadInput"><div class="k-widget k-upload k-upload-async k-upload-empty"><div class="k-dropzone"><div class="k-button k-upload-button" aria-label="Select files"><input type="file" name="files" id="files1" class="clsfiles" data-role="upload" multiple="multiple" autocomplete="off"><span>Select files</span></div><em class="k-dropzone-hint">Drop files here to upload</em></div></div>
         
         </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have a minimum, reproducible, and working example we can stick in the Telerik Dojo? Your question is unclear but I have placed an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your questions says - How do i add fontawesome icon to Kendo UI upload button.
First, add the font awesome CSS `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" />`.
Second, put `<i class="fab fa-accusoft"></i>` between your button tags.
Now your upload button has a font awesome icon. Try the code below in the Telerik Dojo.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.1.119/styles/kendo.default-v2.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" />

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.1.119/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
<style>
  .k-clear-selected,
  .k-upload-selected {
    display: none !important;
  }
</style>

<input name="files" id="files" type="file" />
<button id="uploadAll" class="k-button"><i class="fab fa-accusoft"></i>Start upload</button>
<script>

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#files").kendoUpload({
      async: {
        autoUpload: false,
        saveUrl: "http://my-app.localhost/save",
        removeUrl: "http://my-app.localhost/remove"
      }
    });

    $("#uploadAll").on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();

      var upload = $("#files").data("kendoUpload");
      upload.upload();
    })
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible way is to create a `font-face` for FontAwesome font and replace kendo icons by the FontAwesome icon you want to use.

First, you need to download the `.otf` for the icon gallery you want to use (Light for example). Store it in a folder inside your app and create a css `font-face`.

**styles.scss**

```
/* Font Awesome */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome Light';
    src: url('./assets/fonts/Font Awesome 5 Pro-Light-300.otf');
}
```

Then you'll be able to overwrite kendo's icons by overwriting their css classes. For example, if you want to overwrite the Kendo filter icon with the FontAwesome filter icon, use this

**styles.scss**

```
.k-i-filter::before {
    content: '\f0b0';
    font-family: 'FontAwesome Light';
}
```

*You can find the unicode in the FontAwesome documentation for earch icon [see this example](https://i.gyazo.com/da422ff54d76c413a57131ac4919a182.png)*

Now, each time you use the Kendo filter icon, it will be replaced by the FontAwesome filter icon. So in your case, use

```
<button kendoButton icon="filter"></button>
```